# How to load the configurations from .env during the app startup?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, quasar

I have a quasar app that uses [DOTENV - Quasar Framework app extension](https://github.com/quasarframework/app-extension-dotenv) to load configurations from file `.env`.

When the quasar app gets build, then it will load all the configurations from `.env` file but I want to load the `.env` file when the app get started.

The app runs on Kubernetes and all the configurations are stored as`ConfigMap`. During the container startup, I mount the `.env` file as the following:

```
      containers:
        - name: argo-ui-test
          image: "example.io/ui/argo-ui-test:0.1.9"
          volumeMounts:
          - name: svc-config-url
            mountPath: /app/.env
            subPath: .env
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          resources:
            {}
      volumes:
        - name: svc-config-url
          configMap:
            name: svc-url
```

When I look inside the container, the file has been successfully mounted:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Oct 17 10:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Oct 17 10:33 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    97 Oct 17 10:33 .env
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   494 Oct  6 09:12 50x.html
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 17 09:33 css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16645 Oct 17 09:33 favicon.ico
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 17 09:33 fonts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 17 09:33 icons
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   905 Oct 17 09:33 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 17 09:33 js
I have no name!@argo-ui-test-5c65cb78dc-jnshk:/app$ cat .env
KC_SVC_URL=https://oic.dev.example.io/auth/
USER_SVC_URL=https://user.dev.svc.example.io/api/
```

The quasar app does not load the configurations from `.env` file when it starts.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables actually get referenced and baked into the built artifacts at build time (`npm build` stage), not run time.

If you want to change them at run time. you have to do a little more work. one method that works with me is providing a custom entry point shell script (in your docker file for example):

```
CMD ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And the shell script would have:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Replace env vars in JavaScript files
echo "Replacing env vars in JS"
for file in app/js/app.*.js;
do
  echo "Processing $file ...";

  # Use the existing JS file as template
  if [ ! -f $file.tmpl.js ]; then
    cp $file $file.tmpl.js
  fi

  envsubst '$VUE_APP_BACKEND_HOST' < $file.tmpl.js > $file
done

echo "Starting Nginx"
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

This will change any instances of `$VUE_APP_BACKEND_HOST` from the built code with the current environment variable passed to the kube pod/docker run, this shell actually starts an nginx to serve the files, but you can change it to anything you want

I also use this script as a helper in the App to reference all vars from one place, i only use .env files during development, when deploying i use config maps to map these values directly to env vars.

```js
export default class Configuration {
  static get CONFIG () {
    return {
      backendHost: '$VUE_APP_BACKEND_HOST',
    }
  }

  static value (name) {
    if (!(name in this.CONFIG)) {
      console.log(`Configuration: There is no key named "${name}"`)
      return
    }

    const value = this.CONFIG[name]

    if (!value) {
      console.log(`Configuration: Value for "${name}" is not defined`)
      return
    }

    if (value.startsWith('$VUE_APP_')) {
      // value was not replaced, it seems we are in development.
      // Remove $ and get current value from process.env
      const envName = value.substr(1)
      const envValue = process.env[envName]
      if (envValue) {
        return envValue
      } else {
        console.log(`Configuration: Environment variable "${envName}" is not defined`)
      }
    } else {
      // value was already replaced, it seems we are in production.
      return value
    }
  }
}
```